# Reconhecer a tecla 'enter' em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação

Estou tentando fazer um código que imprima apenas a terceira para de uma string digitada, porém meu programa está sem fim, como reconhecer o enter dado para que o programa finalize?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char **texto= NULL;
int i=0,j;
char letra;

do{
    texto=(char**) realloc(texto, (i+1)*sizeof(char*));
        do{ texto[i]= NULL;
            j=0;
            letra=getchar();
            texto[i]=(char*)realloc(texto[i], (j+1)*sizeof(char));
            texto[i][j]=letra;
            if ((i+1)%3==0){
                printf("%c", letra);
            }
            j++;
        }while(letra!=' ');
        i++;
        printf("%d", (int)letra);
}while ((int)letra!=10);

free(texto);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem certeza que precisa de toda essa complicação e ineficiência? É algum requisito? O jeito mais correto de fazer isso não é assim. Boa parte do que esse código faz é inclusive inútil. Nunca use um código como esse em situação real.

Para resolver o problema tem que analisar se foi digitado um pulo de linha que varia de acordo com o sistema operacional então não pode usar um código fixo, tem que adotar o caractere genérico que indica quebra de linha, assim o compilador coloca o código correto.

Na verdade o código tem vários erros. Um deles é que tem que analisar se foi digitado o fim de linha no laço interno também.

Tinha inicializações de variável no local errado.

Fiz outras melhorias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char **texto = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    char letra;
    do {
        texto = realloc(texto, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        texto[i] = NULL;
        int j = 0;
        do {
            letra = getchar();
            texto[i] = realloc(texto[i], j + 1);
            texto[i][j] = letra;
            if (i == 2) printf("%c", letra);
            j++;
        } while (letra != ' ' && letra != '\n');
        i++;
    } while (letra != '\n');
    free(texto);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/X46v8F). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cdblqmny-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ReadWords.c).

Comment: Boa noite! Eu havia pegado um código base e adaptado ele para as minhas necessidades, tinha requisitos do uso de ponteiros e alocação dinâmica, me perdi um pouco nisso. Mas agradeço pela ajuda, o que preciso me focar mais para dominar essa parte? Eu conseguiria transformar a variável letra para inteiro e usar os caracteres da tabela ASCII ao invés de '\n'?

Comment: Primeiro domine a lógica simples. Segundo pegue algo para fazer uso de ponteiros de forma que seja como se usa realmente, ficar fazendo esse monte de realocações só funciona em exercício

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não faz assim:

```
while ( scanf("%...",&...) != EOF )
{
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```